# Force class FIELD initialization via initializer then make it readonly in C#

Tags: c#

Below С# class has not the properties and I don't want to add them until they actually required.

```cs
public class Person
{

  public required uint ID;
  public required string Name;
  public required string Email;
  public required string PhoneNumber;
  public byte? Age;

  
  public Person Clone()
  {
    return new Person
    {
      ID = ID,
      Name = Name,
      Email = Email,
      PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber,
      Age = Age
    };
  }
  
}
```

Next, I want to make the ID `readonly`. However, if I'll add `readonly` keyword, it will be error

> Required member 'MyProject.Entities.Person.ID' must be settable

Ideally, it should be `init` keyword for the class field, however, as far as I collected the information, this keyword is only for the properties...

#### Why I don't like below solutions

##### Initialize the `ID` via constructor

I will avoid the usage of the constructor until position parameters will not be discarded from the language.

```
// What is 45? The age?!
new Person(45);
```

The programmers WILL avoid the named parameters while its usage is optional - it is the human nature.

##### Replace the fields with properties

I am admitting that I am wrong, but from the viewpoint of logic, the properties are useless while getters are only returns the value and setters are only sets it, herewith getters and setters are public.

```cs
public class Person
{

  public uint ID { get; init; }
  public required string Name;
  
  // ...
  
  public Person Clone()
  {
    return new Person
    {
      ID = ID,
      Name = Name,
      Email = Email,
      PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber,
      Age = Age
    };
  }
  
}
```

looks more or less normal, but I am feeling uncomfortable about class has became a little bit complex.

Comment: "I don't want to add them until they actually required" What do you mean? Do you realise that turning fields into properties breaks binary compatibility? Classes that use `Person`'s fields would need to be recompiled if you change them to properties later. How about just use properties from the get-go?

Comment: I don't understand why you're so adverse to properties. `public uint ID { get; init; }` does exactly what you're after. What do you mean by "from the viewpoint of logic, the properties are useless"?

Comment: Correction to my code snippet: `public required uint ID { get; init; }`

Comment: also properties have many uses that serve logic. Validation of input, logging of get and set, synthetic properties that do not map to backing variables, locking.....

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for the comment. "Do you realise that turning fields into properties breaks binary compatibility?" - Not exactly. Please let me to confirm one thing. Will binary compatibility be broken if the solution where one dependecy has been updated (field has changed to same-name property) has been rebuild? Is it goes without saying - to rebuild the solution once one or more dependencies has been updated?

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank you for the comment. "I don't understand why you're so adverse to properties." - I has not decided yet adverse I to properties or not. What I want is simple: remove the husk from my code, but other works, keep the code simple as possible and use the C# features on demand.

Comment: @pm100 Thank you for the comment. I agree with what you have said - the properties is realy powerfull functional. However the current topic is about get the cleanest code for the current targets.